# Display JSON in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this JSON file in local machine. How to get value **Experiences>roles>title** . Project in react native.

```
"Experiences": [
{
  "companyName": "Demo1 Technologies",
  "logo": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/No_image_available.svg",
  "url": "https://www.google.com/",
  "roles": [
    {
      "title": "Full Stack Developer",
      "description": "Built and updated various Chrome Extensions.",
      "startDate": "2017-01-01",
      "endDate": "2017-05-01",
      "location": "New York, USA"
    }
  ]
},
```

Comment: this is not json. first you need to parse then access through Experiences[0].roles[0].title.

Comment: edit my question Vahid, since I could not figure out

Comment: check this i resolved https://stackoverflow.com/a/58541283/6544460

Comment: check this example in react native https://stackoverflow.com/a/58541384/6544460

Comment: Vahid do you have socials ?

Comment: i didn't get you?

Comment: how i can get in touch with you via social networking?

Comment: Ok, you can connect me through https://www.linkedin.com/in/vaheed-akhtar-97a761a4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In react native**

```
const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([
  {
    "companyName": "Demo1 Technologies",
    "logo": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/No_image_available.svg",
    "url": "https://www.google.com/",
    "roles": [
      {
        "title": "Full Stack Developer",
        "description": "Built and updated various Chrome Extensions.",
        "startDate": "2017-01-01",
        "endDate": "2017-05-01",
        "location": "New York, USA"
      }
    ]
  }]));
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <View>
              <Text>{item.roles[0].title}</Text>
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([
{
  "companyName": "Demo1 Technologies",
  "logo": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/No_image_available.svg",
  "url": "https://www.google.com/",
  "roles": [
    {
      "title": "Full Stack Developer",
      "description": "Built and updated various Chrome Extensions.",
      "startDate": "2017-01-01",
      "endDate": "2017-05-01",
      "location": "New York, USA"
    }
  ]
}]));
console.log(res[0].roles[0].title);
```

Comment: Vahid do you have a simpler version?

Comment: how to implement this in react native ? Y

Comment: @JasurKurbanov this is the way because previously it was string.